Why $h_{21}=||\textbf{v}||$ ? where $h_{21}$ is the (2,1)-entry of upper hessenberg form.
I was trying to find the $\vec{q}_2$ using the Arnoldi method described here.
Why $h_{21}=||\vec{v}||$ ?
My attempt:-
Suppose we took arbitrary vector as $\vec{q_1}$.
Then $$A[\vec{q_1}]=[\vec{q_1} \vec{q_2}]\[\begin{matrix}
  h_{11} \\
 h_{12}
\end{matrix}\]^T$$
Hence $$\vec{q_2}=\frac{A\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1}}{h_{21}}.$$
We need to have $\langle \vec{q_1}, \vec{q_2}\rangle=0$
we get $h_{11}=\vec{q_1}^\star A \vec{q_1}.$
We let $\vec{v}=A\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1}$
$$||\vec{v}||^2=(A\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1})^\star (A\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1})$$
$$=(\vec{q_1}^\star A-h_{11}\vec{q_1}^\star) (A\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1})=\vec{q_1}^\star AA\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1}^\star A\vec{q_1}-h_{11}\vec{q_1}^\star A\vec{q_1}+h_{11}^2$$
I don't understand how does it become $h_{21}^2$
Please help me.

Your text defines $h_{21}$ as the length of the vector $v = Aq_1 - h_{11} q_1$. At first glance, there is nothing to show here. On the other hand, your text does not prove that the Arnoldi algorithm is correct. I think that this is your real question. Am I right?

@CarlChristian Thank you. I thought that I need to show it. Yeah. I think I am not getting the general formula from this text. I proved it separately $q_{n+1}=\frac{Aq_n-\sum_{i=1}^n h_{n,i}q_i}{h_{n+1,n}}$. Am I correct? Then I took numeraor as $v$ and $h_{n+1,n}=||v||$.

You have found the correct formula. Your text contains a very common issue. It does not actually prove that the Arnoldi algorithm produces a factorization of the form $AV = VH$ where the columns of $V$ span the required subspaces. Rather, it proves that if the factorization exists, then it can computed as suggested. It is not important that you resolve this issue now, but at some point you may wish to prove the algorithm correct. It is standard to skip/suppress the proof because the technical details obfuscates the points the author is trying to make.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4928411/derive-lanczos-algorithm-by-imitating-the-derivation-of-arnoldi-iteration-algori

in this note they don't talk about the Lanczos iteration much. i tried like this. Am I correct?
