Derive Lanczos algorithm by imitating the derivation of Arnoldi iteration algorithm.
If A is Hermitian, then everything above simplifies (e.g., Hessenberg matrices
turn into tridiagonal), and we get what is know in the literature separately as Lanczos
iteration.
My attempt:-
Derivation of Lanczos algorithm imitating the derivation of Arnoldi iteration algorithm
Consider the special Hessenberg form Tridiagonal matrix $T_n=\tilde{H}_{n+1,n}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_1 & 0&...&0\\
\beta_1 & \alpha_2 & \beta_1&...&0\\
0 & \beta_2 & \alpha_3&...&0\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots&\alpha_{n-1}&\beta_{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0&\beta_{n-1}&\alpha_n\\
0 & 0 & 0&0&\beta_n\\
\end{bmatrix}$
Consider the first step. Choose a unit vector $\vec{q_1}.$
For $\vec{q_2},$ Consider the equation
$$A[\vec{q_1}]=[\vec{q}_1 \vec{q}_2] \begin{bmatrix} 
                                     \alpha_1\\ 
                                     \beta_1 
                                      \end{bmatrix}$$
From this we get $\vec{q}_2=\frac{A\vec{q}_1-\alpha_1 \vec{q}_1}{\beta_1}$
Choose $\vec{v}=A\vec{q}_1-\alpha_1 \vec{q}_1$
$\beta_1=||\vec{v}||.$
We know that $\vec{q}_1^\star \vec{q}_2=\vec{q}_1^\star (A\vec{q}_1-\alpha_1 \vec{q}_1)=0$
hence $\alpha_1=\vec{q}_1^\star A\vec{q}_1.$
Generalizing,
We get $\vec{q}_{n+1}=\frac{A \vec{q}_{n}-\beta_{n-1}\vec{q}_{n-1}-\alpha_n \vec{q}_{n}}{\beta_n}.$
Choose $\vec{v}^\star=A \vec{q}_{n}-\beta_{n-1}\vec{q}_{n-1}-\alpha_n \vec{q}_{n}$ and
$||A \vec{q}_{n}-\beta_{n-1}\vec{q}_{n-1}-\alpha_n \vec{q}_{n}||=\beta_n$
Using the orthogonality, we get
$\alpha_n=\vec{q}_n^\star A\vec{q}_n$
$\beta_{n-1}=\vec{q}_{n-1}^\star A\vec{q}_n$
Am I correct?

Yes and no. The key point to explain is why you do not divide by zero.

I don't understand@CarlChristian

In order to define $q_2$ you are dividing with $\beta_1$. You need to show that $\beta_1$ is nonzero. You need to involve the dimension of smallest $A$ invariant vector space that contains the vector $q_1$.

Could you help me to  understand the following spectral approximation?@CarlChristian https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4929441/prove-that-sigmat-n-n-subset-sigmaa

@CarlChristian Here, in this question. You mean I need to pick $\vec{q_1}$ in such a way that $A\vec{q_1}\neq \alpha \vec{q_1}. $ Right?
